# Is there any way to parse an APNG with an unmodified libpng?

Tags: c++, png, libpng, irrlicht, apng

I'd like to parse APNGs without modifying libpng. This is important because libpng may get security patches and if I modify libpng I need to maintain my version of it.

Is there any way to parse APNGs without a modified libpng?

Comment: The apng patch gets security updates usually the same day as libpng gets them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky, but possible.
See the source code for apng disassembler:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/apngdis/

Comment: Doesn't libpng have a built-in way to read "custom" PNG chunks? Why the whole custom implementation?

Comment: Yes it does, but this implementation is basically remuxing apng into sequence of regular pngs which are then decoded by libpng. It's more straightforward to implement that remuxing process just by parsing chunks.

Comment: Another implementation can be found in WebKit: https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/platform/image-decoders/png It uses that build-in way to read custom chunks that you mentioned, but lack of access to "raw" info chunks also makes it more tricky.

Comment: But in theory that means it supports more PNG chunks, instead of just the APNG chunks.

Comment: Not really. Remuxing is just shuffling chunks around. There is no need for apngdis to "understand" any other chunks, when it could just copy them "as is". Look at #defines in apngdis source code - it can only "understand" 6 chunks, 3 of them APNG.

Comment: But how does it handle color correction chunks and stuff?

Comment: After remuxing apng into sequence of regular pngs those are then decoded by libpng. This includes color correction chunks and stuff. apngdis doesn't need to "understand" them, it just needs to copy them.